# Minimum Blackberry version supported by phonegap v2.2?

Tags: cordova, blackberry

I am trying to find this info from phonegap website and from google groups, but none available. I was not able to deploy a simple hello world app on to a Blackberry v4.6. Is this a requirement of phonegap or am I missing anything?
PS: I have signed the app with the keys obtained from Blackberry before attempting to deploy on the device.
I have also tried to deploy through `ant blackberry load-device` and through the blackberry desktop manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [list](http://phonegap.com/about/feature), Blackberry OS 5.x and Blackberry OS 6.0+  are supported. In [Apache Cordova document](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_blackberry_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20with%20Blackberry), its mentioned

> Cordova for BlackBerry makes use of the BlackBerry WebWorks framework.
>   BlackBerry WebWorks tooling is available for Windows or Mac
>   environments. WebWorks applications can ONLY be deployed to BlackBerry
>   devices running OS 5.0 and higher or the BlackBerry PlayBook operating
>   system.